# Ways to minimize additional driver surcharges on car hire

Tags: car-rentals, price

When hiring a car for a holiday well in advance, it is often possible to achieve very low rates. However, especially if there is a large amount of driving on the holiday, it would be desirable to be able to share the driving duties. However the problem here is that while the car hire rates may be discounted or adjusted with respect to demand, booking and discount codes, additional driver fees are often fixed. Frequently, fixed so high that they cost as much as the daily hire cost in fact (when getting a discounted rate). Are there any (generalized, or specific deals with major international chains) of making this cost more reasonable?

Comment: Can you put a specific country in your question? There might be a nation chain X which is only available in country Y, so the answer list would be too long.

Comment: I could, but I hire in all sorts of different countries. I'm looking for either stratergies that work in general, or for specific deals/T&Cs/perks offered by one of the international chains. Not asking for local-only deals.

Comment: Can we assume you're not asking about having a spouse or family member do the driving?  Are you specifically looking for methods that work with friends or otherwise unrelated drivers?

Comment: @Joe I'm happy to hear about methods that let a person of a defined relationship also drive the hire car. Eg "Yes with Europocar, provided the other person is a spouse" would be an answer I'm happy to see. Sure, generic extra drivers is even more useful, but just anyone to share the driving with would be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

That depends very much on the country. In New Zealand, we've never paid extra for a second driver. In the US, fees for a second driver are very common. In Germany it's been mixed but also typically cheaper than in the US. It's unlikely that a single "one size fits all" strategy would be useful. For the US, check out http://millionmilesecrets.com/2013/04/02/car-rental-additional-driver/